# Reporting Services grafica de barras

Tags: sql-server, reportviewer, ssrs

Como puedo mostrar minutos en el eje Y de la grafica de barras, estoy utilizando Report Builder 3.0

este es el resultado del query que quiero mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo maximo que puede tener son los 5 dias de la semana(L-V), el dia de la semana me aparece en el eje X y el tiempo me aparece en la barra y es correcto, pero en el eje Y solo aparecen 1 como en la imagen siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como puedo hacer que la misma hora que aparece en la barra tambiene este en el eje Y?

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de buscar información por la red, encontre algun ejemplo de lo que buscaba y me ayudo a resolver mi problema.

Les dejo el link por si alguien más lo necesita;

[SSRS: Display static time range on y-axis](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdcda8c0-9140-49e5-9357-7c957b7c349a/solved-ssrs-display-static-time-range-on-yaxis?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Esta en ingles.

Saludos.